# add variable to json

Tags: javascript, php, json

So there are many questions on here about this and I tried quite a few without success.

I am trying to add a php variable to a javascript variable and then put it in json.

```
<?php $symbol_json =  $row['symbol_json']; echo $symbol_json; ?> <!--This is OK!-->
</div>
</center>
<center>
<!-- Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="widget-container">
  <div class="widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="widget-copyright"><a href="https://aaaaaaa.com/symbols/<?php echo $row['symbol_html']; ?>/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text"><?php echo $row['symbol']?> Symbol Info</span></a></div>

  <script>
    var myVar = '<?php echo $symbol_json ?>'; alert(myVar); //This works ok!

    var myObject = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($symbol_json) ?>'); alert(myObject); //Alert works ok!
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://aaaaaaa.com/external-embedding/symbol-info.js" async>
  {
  //"symbol": "SDT", //This how it is at present and it works. I need to change it to a variable like below.
  "symbol": myObject, //Whether I use myObject or myVar (which both contain SDT) the widget loads a different symbol. 
  "width": 1000,
  "locale": "uk",
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "isTransparent": false
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- Widget END -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you put your variables into the same script tag? As a general advice, please, please, please don't mix up PHP with Javascript or HTML. It's the best way to make your code smell.  You must parse yout JSON in order to use it as a variable, so

```
 var myObject = '<?php echo json_encode($symbol_json) ?>';
```

becames

```
 var myObject = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($symbol_json) ?>');
```

Comment: @technicalDifficulties please send me the output of console.log(myObject); otherwise it's difficult to understand your error

Comment: this is the error: Widget settings parse error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 14
h._scriptContentToJSON @ embed-widget-symbol-info.js:1

Comment: when I click into the link it goes into a whole load of code in relation to the widget. Too much to paste here but I definitely can see the default symbol appearing in and amongst the code so it is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I could simply add: `"symbol": "<?php echo $symbol_json ?>",` although placing PHP into a JS variable worked in a different instance, this seemed to work here. The console error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON -- said basically that m (was the first letter of myObject was the error). myObject was therefore not being treated as a variable.